# Update single column in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, hector, cassandra-0.7

I have following cassandra column family:

```
create column family cfn
 with comparator = UTF8Type
 and key_validation_class = UUIDType
 and column_metadata =[
      {column_name:email, validation_class: UTF8Type,index_type: KEYS}
      {column_name:full_name, validation_class: UTF8Type}
 ];
```

I want to update "full_name" of given "email" but i don't know the row key i only have "email". How can i do that using hector thrift api?

I know that i will have to insert a new column as there is no update kind of thing in cassandra. Will it be necessary to get row key before inserting new column for the same row?

Answer (score 0):

Inserting using cassandra-cli or hector is the most basic thing. May be you need to brush your cassandra repo [Read This](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/cql_cli/using_cli).

Try this using cli

```
SET cfn[RowKey]['full_name']='XYZ'; 
/*
 *Remember you have mentioned your key as UUID Type. So while providing a Rowkey it should   
 *be in UUID type only. e.g  8aff3820-1e55-11b2-a248-41825ac3edd8
 */
SET cfn[RowKey]['email']='XYZ@GMAIL.COM';
```

Retrieve Data,

```
list cfn;
```

Comment: can you share **describe #KeyspaceName** output from cqlsh shell?

Comment: FYI, when you create a columnfamily from cli, by default rowkey name is **key** of type **uuid**

Comment: Imagine a web application. Will it be a safe option to send row key in a response. It may be dangerous to alter the DB. am i right

Comment: Not always necessarily. Though if you don't want that discrepancy try to create column family from any of cassandra client API's or cql shell.